# Converting a PDO object to a Javascript JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, pdo

I am currently trying to convert a PDO object into a javascript JSON.

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
  $personArray = array();
  $queryResult = < this gets the valid result of a $statement->fetchall(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC) >

  foreach($queryResult as $p){

      $personArray[] = array(
                        "Id" => $p["Id"],
                        "Name" => $p["Name"],
                        "Text" => $p["Text"]
      );
  }

  echo json_encode($personArray);
```

Note that I tried to do `json_encode($queryResult);` before, but it seems like I would have to change the enconding on all my statements which I don't want to do.

Here is my recieving JS:
function refreshEntries(){

```
$.ajax({
    url: "< my PHP file >",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(returnPDO){

        var obj = JSON.parse(returnPDO);

        ...
    }
});
```

}

The Javascript, to be more precide the `JSON.parse(returnPDO);` is the breaking point. I get the `" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a "` error message everytime, and I am very sure that is coming from the `array()` which stands at the beginning of my array in PHP.

There must be some fault here, but I can't figure out what exactly. I guess I know where the error is, but not how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: Depending on stuff and things, you might not even need json.parse. sometimes jquery parses it automagically. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: If you set `dataType: "json"`, jquery will automagically parse it as json. Use the browser developer tools to see the full response from server.

Comment: If you have jQueryo, you don't need a parser.

Answer (score 1):

you are already fetching your pdo as an associative array so why not just json_encode your pdo result?

```
  $toReturn = json_encode($queryResult);
  echo $toReturn;
```

also you haven't set your dataType: to json in your ajax call.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "< my PHP file >",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returnPDO){

        var obj = JSON.parse(returnPDO);

        ...
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

your json must fit a specification, it should be a utf-8 string with no special characters in it. the properties names must be surrounded by double quotes and and and ...

I recomend you get some sample of your data and submit it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ this will parse your json and give you a glue about what is wrong